# basic html! i wanna ad a black box to my page

Tags: html, css

im new in coding.
I want add a box to my page. The box must be centered how can i do?

I did try that codes but isn't working.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fnt7B.png)

```
.panel{
    
    background-color: #FF2D00;
    border-radius: 10px;
    height: 25.625em;
    left: 5em;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;   
} 

<div id="panel"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give your element a width and also use a class attribute in your html.

```css
.panel{ 
    background-color: #FF2D00;
    border-radius: 10px;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) 
}
```

```html
<div class="panel"></div>
```

Comment: @DavidsaysreinstateMonica The element absolutely positioned so it needs a width if the element has no content inside. If you remove the width, the element disappears.

Comment: hey, i wanna make center as horizontal prnt.sc/155640h how can i do? btw sorry4 my bad english

Comment: If you want to use position: absolute then you can use `left: 50%;  top: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%)` as per my answer.

Comment: k. thx again, i love y'all <3

Answer (score 0):

```
#panel{
    background-color: #FF2D00;
    border-radius: 10px;
    height: 25.625em;
    width: 300px;
    left: 5em;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%
    left:0;
    right:0;
    margin: auto;
} 

<div id="panel"></div>
```

1. Give the element a width
2. Set the left and right to 0
3. Set the margin to auto
4. and lastly change the selector to #

:)

Answer (score -1):

You can use `margin: 0 auto;` to horizontally centered the box

```css
.panel{ 
    background-color: #000000;
    border-radius: 10px;
    height: 25.625em;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;   
}
```

```html
<div class="panel"></div>
```

Comment: hey, i wanna make center as horizontal https://prnt.sc/155640h how can i do?